# Python Multiprocessing : How to pass objects?

Tags: python, multithreading, object, serial-port, instance

I'm using multiprocessing to run the "start" function which is responsible for reading data from serial port.

But the problem is that after I finish reading I'm not able to close the port because I don't know how to pass the "s" object out to the main program.
So my questions are:

1. how I could pass the "s" object to the "stop" function?
2. does `bring_data.terminate()` solve the problem?

In other words, does it destroy the objects inside the "start" function too? (so maybe I could recreate the object and then use it to close the port)

```
def start(x ,y ,z) :
    # creat object s :
    s = serial.Serial()
    s.baudrate = 115200
    s.port = 'COM4'
    s.open()
    print("the port is opened")

def stop(obj) :
    obj.close()
    print("the port is closed")

if __name__ == "__main__" :
get_data = mp.Process(target = start , args = ( x, y ,z ))
get_data.start()
#?????????????
stop(obj)
```

Comment: Passing open ports between processes is not a goid idea. Any reason you are not using a thread?

Comment: because after the data arrives i pass it through several stages of filtering and mathematical equations to get what i want and the _Multiprocessing_ was much more efficient.

Comment: Then the processing should happen in seperate processes, not the input.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently , yes indeed the `bring_data.terminate()` is destroying all objects inside the function including the "s" object and the port closed eventually .
it's not an ideal solution but it do what it takes .